# Xmlpull Java, parsing xml file on internet

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xmlpullparser

I'm testing Xmlpull, I've actually parsed xml locally on my computer.
Now, I would like to parse an XML file on internet, the file is:

http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml

but I can't find a way to stream data to the XmlPullParser object, please give me some general guideline on how to solve this?

An other approach I thought, was to download the xml file via java io and then parse the file locally, but this is not exactly what I was trying to achieve. I would like to parse the xml file directly on on internet, without storing a copy locally.

anyways please tell me the best practice.

Thanks, hope everything is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your intent is to do that with Android APIs, so please translate as appropriate.

In plain Java, there is `XmlStreamReader` for StAX parsing, and it can be instantiated with an `InputStream` from an `URLConnnection`, like this:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;

public class ParseStream {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URLConnection connection =
      new URL("http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml").openConnection();
    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    XMLStreamReader streamReader =
      XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    while (streamReader.hasNext())
      if (streamReader.next() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT)
        System.out.println("START_ELEMENT " + streamReader.getName());
  }
}
```

In fact I would refine it somewhat, e.g. get the encoding out of the URLConnection rather than using a fixed one.

But it should give the idea.